# How to print the letters of the first word in a phrase, assuming there will always be three words in a phrase

Tags: java

I am pretty sure I have the right idea for the following code but something seems wrong where it's not able to capture the letters of the first word in a 3-word phrase. This has to be done using for loop and my code worked for finding the second-word letters in a 3-word phrase, but it's not working for the first one. I'm assuming that there is something I am missing, so could you look at my code and make corrections where necessary. I don't want any other solutions, I would like to use the same method I used for everything else.

sample input: The grey elephant

Sample output: first word has 3 letters

code:

```
else if (option == 3){
            int first = -1;
            int last = -1;
            for (int x = 0; x < phrase.length(); x++){
                char n = phrase.charAt(x);
                if (n == phrase.charAt(0)){
                    first = x;
                }
                else if (n == ' '){
                    last = x;
                }
            }
                    int length = first - last;
                        System.out.print("First word has "+length+" letters");

    }
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input (`phrase`), expected & actual "output"?

Comment: I did Scott Hunter

Comment: You realize you can just do `phrase.split(" ", 2)[0].length()`, right?

Comment: No, it has to be done using for loop

Comment: Expected *and* actual output?

Comment: You can `break` the loop after counting the `last`

Comment: Sample input: The grey elephant ----> Sample output:  first word has 3 letters

Comment: @am0awad Not only can he, he has to

Comment: What. Is. The. Actual (supposedly incorrect). Output.

Comment: @ScottHunter I'm guessing it's "First word has 8 letters"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not stopping your loop after you find your ' '.  You need a break

```
else if (n == ' '){
                    last = x;
                    break;
                }
```